# Создание json файла c помощью python

Tags: python, json

Существуют два словаря:

```
ps_total = {'load.connections.aborts': 'Total', 'load.connections.running': 'Total', 'load.connections.attempts_ps': 'Per Second', 'load.connections.succeeds_ps': 'Per Second', 'load.scenarios.succeeds': 'Total', 'load.actions.attempts_ps': 'Per Second', 'load.actions.fails': 'Total'}

Load = {'load.connections.aborts': 'Load', 'load.connections.running': 'Load', 'load.connections.attempts_ps': 'Load', 'load.connections.succeeds_ps': 'Load', 'load.scenarios.succeeds': 'Load', 'load.actions.attempts_ps': 'Load', 'load.actions.fails': 'Load'}
```

на основе их ключей и значений нужно сформировать json файл такого вида примерно

```
{ 
    "name" : "load.scenarios.attempts",
    "kind" : "Total",
    "category" : "Load"
}
```

я попытался сделать это с помощью библиотеки json

```
print(json.dumps({'name': '???', 'kind': '???', 'category' : '???'}, 
 sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))`
```

На месте вопросительных знаков должны быть ключи и значения из словарей, но как их туда подставить я не знаю, я пытался через `dict.keys()`.
но не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите, то вот так:

```
merged = [
          {'name': key, 'kind': ps_total[key], 'category': Load[key]}
          for key in ps_total.keys()
          ]

res = json.dumps(merged,
                 sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
print(res)
```