# Добавление объекта json python

Tags: python, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне добавить json объект в файл при помощи python.
Вот объект

```
      "name": "CeilingSkylight",
      "uniqueId": 14863.6865,
      "position": {
        "x": -121.896072,
        "y": -2.105801,
        "z": -0.7743931
      },
      "rotation": {
        "x": 0.9970698,
        "y": -1.63123222E-08,
        "z": -0.07649757,
        "w": 2.05165609E-08
      },
      "isKinematic": true,
      "instantiationData": null,
      "runtimeData": null
    }
```

Уточняю: открыть файл, добавить объект json(так что бы другие не удалились), закрыть файл

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание json файла c помощью python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755592/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-json-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-python)

Comment: @MrP точно не дубликат того вопроса, там вопрос про соединение словарей скорее, а не про конвертацию в json.

Comment: @insolor, поторопился ( ´･･)ﾉ(._.`)

Comment: с чем конкретно проблема? С открыть файл, с добавить объект, с закрыть файл?

Comment: "Уточняю: открыть файл, добавить объект json(так что бы другие не удалились), закрыть файл" - никак, json не поддерживает "дозапись". Только прочитать json из файла полностью, добавить в него свои данные, перезаписать данные в файле полностью.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В комментариях вам верно указали, что нет возможности добавлять записи в json файл. Вы можете записывать, читать, перезаписывать, добавлять в конец файла, добавлять в определенную строку, но все что описано выше - это работа с текстовыми данными, а не с сущностями json или python.

Верный порядок действий такой:

1. открыть и прочитать файл (это будет последовательность символов)
2. прочитанную последовательность с помощью json модуля сделать понятным для python словарем
3. Изменить нужное значение(-я) в словаре
4. Преобразовать словарь в формат json (для python это будет опять последовательность символов, грубо говоря строка)
5. Полностью перезаписать файл

```py
import json

# 1, 2
open with("your.json") as f:
    json_str = json.load(f)

# 3
json_str["name"] = "new_name"

# 4, 5
open with("your.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(json_str, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

используя библиотеку json

```
import json

data = {
    "name": "CeilingSkylight",
    "uniqueId": 14863.6865,
    "position": {
        "x": -121.896072,
        "y": -2.105801,
        "z": -0.7743931
    },
    "rotation": {
        "x": 0.9970698,
        "y": -1.63123222E-08,
        "z": -0.07649757,
        "w": 2.05165609E-08
    },
    "isKinematic": True,
    "instantiationData": None,
    "runtimeData": None
}

json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(json_data)
```

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос